# Sorting numpy lists

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am having troubles working with NumPy arrays as I am new to NumPy.
I have a big input which I read with `sys.stdin`, which is consisted of lines with 2 values and a space between them, representing a point or two coordinates. I then save it in a list which looks something like this:

```
np.array([[1, 3], [5, 6], [7, 2], [9, 9]])
```

I want to sort the list by their sums and then by their x-coordinate, but I am not sure how to do this.

I am also not sure how would I add that sum as the third element of each sublist, in case I wanted to add it.

Comment: Is this Python2.7 or 3?

Comment: What would be the expected output for the sample data?

Comment: Is you data already sorted by the x coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on python's built-in `sorted` is inefficient for numpy-arrays, especially when these are big. Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([[1, 3], [5, 6], [7, 2], [9, 9]])

ind = np.lexsort((l[:,0], l.sum(axis=1)))

sorted_l = l[ind]
```

`ind` will contain the indices of your original array, sorted by the two arrays given to `lexsort`. The last array is the primary sort column for `lexsort`. `l[ind]` selects these indices from your original array.

Comment: Great answer but I think you edited it the wrong way by mistake. The first answer gave me the result I wanted, now it sorts by x coordinate and then by sums :)

Comment: Hu, weird. I first posted without testing the code and then edited after testing, because it gave the wrong result. [The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort) also say the last column is the primary column. I"ll check again

Comment: @Larisa It is correct that you are expecting `array([[1, 3],
       [7, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [9, 9]])`, right?